# How to take value of li in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul class="ul_nav">
    <li ng-repeat="teams in teamArray"  ng-click="changeClass('{{ teams.team_name }}')">
        {{ teams.team_name }}
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>

**Js**

function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.changeClass = function(value){
        alert(value);
    };
    $scope.teamArray = [
        {team_name: 'team 1'},
        {team_name: 'team 2'}
    ];
}
```

Here I can list li items. But when I clicked on li, the alert box shows "{{ teams.team_name }}", instead of team names. How to alert the team name(eg: tem1/team2).
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/470/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-click expects and angular expression. You must not use `{{`in what is already an angular expression:

```
changeClass(teams.team_name)
```

You should also avoid using the plural form for a single value. The variable `teams` should be named `team`, since it holds a *single* team.